# Should I be specifying IQueryable over List in my interfaces?

Tags: c#, interface, ienumerable, iqueryable

I'd like to know whether, when defining my interface, I should prefer IQueryable over List for groups of objects. Or perhaps IEnumerable is better, since IEnumerable types can be cast to IQueryable to be used with LINQ.

I was looking at a course online and it was dealing with EntityFramework, for which it is best to use IQueryable since LINQ uses it (okay there's more to it than that but probably not important right now).
The code below was used, and it got me thinking if I should be specifying IQueryable instead of List for my groups of objects.

```
namespace eManager.Domain
{
    public interface IDepartmentDataSource
    {
        IQueryable<Employee> Employees { get; }
        IQueryable<Department> Departments { get; }
    }
```

If I were building an interface for a service that calls the repository to get Employees, I would usually specify

```
List <Employees>
```

but is this best practice? Would IQueryable give more flexibility to classes that implement my interface? What about the overhead of having to import LINQ if they don't need it (say they only want a List)? Should I use IEnumerable over both of these?

Comment: You should probably tag your question with "C#" in order to raise more attention.

Comment: Oh, LINQ actually uses `IEnumerable` just as easily. The difference is whether you want to provide a set of data which the caller can work with, or a proxy to that data. Personally, I'd go with `IEnumerable` / `IList` unless you have a specific reason to use `IQueryable`. `IQueryable` makes your interface waaaay too wide. Make your interface tighter than "here's all the employees, do whatever you want with them" :)

Comment: With `IQueryable` you are putting a burden on the implementer of the interface. Putting a burden makes sense only if there is a code that requires that interface. Is there a code that screams "I *really* need `IQueryable` right here"?

Comment: @Dialecticus yes that is why I am wondering if IEnumerable is a better option.

Comment: To answer the question about which you are wondering a person must know if there exists a code that screams "I *really* need `IQueryable` right here". Only you know that, so only you can answer your own question. If there is no such code then reduce the burden by simplifying the interface.

Comment: See my comment on @Boris' answer. I feel the service should not know what the client intends to do, so for me IEnumerable is the way to go. If the client wanted filtered data it should have told the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`IQueryable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb351562%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) interface is in effect a query on Entity Framework that is not yet executed. When you call `ToList()`, `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` etc. on `IQueryable` Entity Framework will construct the SQL query and query the database.

[`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the other hand is 'just' an enumerator on a collection. You can use it to filter the collection but you'd use LINQ to Objects. Entity Framework doesn't come into play here.

To answer your question: it depends. If you want the clients of your repository to be able to further customize the queries they can execute you should expose `IQueryable`, but if you want full control in your repository on how the database is queried you could use `IEnumerable`.

I prefer to use `IEnumerable`, because that doesn't leak the use of Entity Framework throughout the application. The repository is responsible for database access. It is also easier to make LINQ to EF optimizations, because the queries are only in the repository.

Comment: From what you said I am feeling that the repository should use IQueryable so it can do the queries with LINQ. The service that calls it should return, to its clients, IEnumerable. The service should say to its client "You've asked me for this data, here it is - I am done". Any further filtering is to be done by the client - the service doesn't care.

Comment: Yes, the repository implicitly uses IQueryable, because that's what Entity Framework exposes. When you return a collection of items from the repository you could return an IEnumerable from the repository. To make sure you don't expose the IQueryable from the repository you should call ToList() on the IQueryable so the SQL query is executed.

Answer (score 2):

What I usually do is make the repositories return `IQueryable`. Then in the BL I specify either `IEnumerable` or `IQueryble`. It is important to know the main differences between `IQueryble` and `IEnumerable`.

Lets say you fetch data into IEnumerable
`IEnumerable employees=this.repository.GetAll();`
Now let's say this specific function require only employees with age over 21 and the others are not needed at all.

You would do:
    `employees.Where(a=>a.Age>21)`
In this case the original query will be loaded in the memory and then the Where will be applied.

Now lets say you change the function to fetch the data into IQueryable
`IQueryable employees=this.repository.GetAll();`
`employees.Where(a=>a.Age>21)`
This time when you modify the query with the Where clause, the whole query will be executed in the database (if possible) and you will only get employees with age over 21 from the database.

In the IEnumerable case you will get all the employees from the database and then they will get filtered in memory to satisfy the where condition.

Use IEnumerable, IList or something else?
If you know what operations will be executed on the collection you can easily choose which interface to use. Basically if you will only iterate over the collection you would use IEnumerable. If you would do more operations you need to choose the appropriate interface. There are good videos of .NET collections in pluralsight.